# How to reference for a FormArray which is in a nested FormGroup?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a FormGroup nested in another FormGroup which includes a FormArray and I want to bind this FormArray in my HTML code.

If I did not nest my FormArray in another FormGroup it works like charm but as soon as it gets another parent it breaks. Binding is not working with dot notation.

My component's code looks like this:

```
this.fb.group({
    outerprop1: ['', Validators.required],
    data: this.fb.group({
        prop1: [''],
        fileList: this.fb.array([this.createFile()]),
        prop2: [''],
    })
});
/***/
get fileList(): FormArray {
     return <FormArray>this.form.get('data.fileList');
}
/***/
createFile(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        id: ['', Validators.required],
        documentType: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

The createfile() method is just returning a FormGroup.

```html
    <div formArrayName="fileList"
        *ngFor="let item of fileList.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i" class="file">
            <app-file-upload-with-description [formControl]="item.get('id')">
            </app-file-upload-with-description>
            <app-dropdown-input [formControl]="item.get('documentType')">
            </app-dropdown-input>
            <button class="delete-button" (click)="removeFile(i)"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to have a successful binding, currently I run in a Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with name: 'fileList'